Can't entropy stop moving objects in a frictionless medium?
I don't know much about thermodynamics and there is a problem that I can't really answer.If entropy tends to go to infinity, that is, if heat energy tends to spread and create high entropy at every moment, shouldn't an object moving in an imaginary world where there is no friction stop after a certain time as a result of the conversion of all its kinetic energy into heat energy and its spread?

And how is this heat energy being created? There isn't any friction as you state.

There is no law that says the entropy of a closed system must continuously increase. There is only a law saying that, in the long run, the entropy cannot decrease. That leaves open the possibility that, in theory, the entropy could remain constant over a long span of time—neither increasing nor decreasing.

Loosely speaking, friction is the process that converts mechanical (kinetic) energy into heat.  If there is no friction, then the object's motion will not create heat.  You have created a special thermodynamic condition in your imaginary world whereby the entropy does not change.  (Incidentally, this is sometimes assumed for theoretical reasons and it is related to process reversibility.)
You could cook up a scheme where some magnetic fields produce eddy currents in the object and the electrical resistance provides heat.  But electrical resistance is basically like friction.
So the general answer to the question is NO.
